# T-SQL Returning records (customers) where value not present

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Ok, this seems like it should be an easy one so I will try to simplify what I am trying to do.

Say I have this select statement:

```
SELECT a.customer, b.fruit
FROM Customer a 
INNER JOIN Order b ON a.customer = b.Customer
```

Which would return the following:

```
Customer         Fruit
-------------------------
Jane             Apple
Jane             Banana
Bob              Apple
Bob              Orange
Bob              Grape
John             Apple
John             Banana
Ann              Tangerine
Ann              Orange
Ann              Banana
```

What I would like to pull from this result set is a list of customers who have never ordered, say, a 'Tangerine', resulting in the following list:

```
     Customer
     --------
      Jane
      Bob
      John
```

How would one go about do this?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer c
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Order
                 WHERE customer = c.customer
                 And Fruit = 'Tangerine');
```

Using `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer c
WHERE c.Customer NOT IN (SELECT Customer FROM Order
                         WHERE Customer IS NOT NULL
                         And Fruit = 'Tangerine');
```

Comment: Excellent!  I believe I have achieved the results I was looking for using the NOT IN.  I am assuming that if I wanted the inverse of these results I would just use IN instead of NOT IN?  Thanks Everyone!

Comment: @Zwick44 I mean, not necessarily, you would need to give more details

Comment: Meaning if I just wanted the list to show those Customers who have at one time ordered a Tangerine.

Comment: @Zwick44 Ah, yeah, in that case using `IN` would work (but if the `customer` column can be `NULL`, then you need to use the `IS NOT NULL` condition)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method using `left join`:

```
SELECT c.customer
FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN
     Order o
     ON c.customer = o.Customer AND o.fruit = 'Tangerine'
WHERE o.Customer IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Existing answers are missing distinct customers

```
SELECT distinct c.customer
  FROM Customer c
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                      FROM Customer T
                     WHERE T.customer = c.customer
                       And T.Fruit = 'Tangerine'
                  );
```

And I don't like tables and column the same
That would be more and Order table